# Laravel Query Builder Stop working after groupBy

Tags: laravel

```
$records = DB::table('history as a')
    ->join('reservation2 as b', function($join){
      $join->on('a.id', '=', 'b.id')
      ->on('a.sid', '=', 'b.sid');
    })
    ->whereBetween('a.date', [$sDate, $eDate])
    ->select('a.*', DB::raw('SUM(a.perday) AS revenue'), 'b.name', 'b.checkin', 'b.checkout', 'b.status')
    ->groupBy('a.id')
    ->groupBy('a.sid')
    ->toSql();
```

Gives me following query:

```
select `a`.*, SUM(a.perday) AS revenue, `b`.`name`, `b`.`checkin`, `b`.`checkout`,
       `b`.`status` 
from `history` as `a` 
inner join `reservation2` as `b` on `a`.`id` = `b`.`id` and `a`.`sid` = `b`.`sid` 
where `a`.`date` between ? and ? group by `a`.`id`, `a`.`sid`
```

Many records are displayed if query is passed from mysql command prompt but if I replace `->toSql()` with `->get()` it does not give me any record.

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the value and type of `$sDate` and `$eDate`? And how do you input them manualy?

Comment: $sDate='2016-12-01' & $eDate='2016-12-05'. Its not the problem of value that is passed correctly.

Comment: Paste your error here

Comment: No error just a blank page. Actually query is not executed. Without groupBy & DB::raw things are working fine.

Comment: So if you do `dd($records)` right after the query, nothing shows? Does Laravel have permissions to write in the log? Are you running MySQL in strict mode?

Comment: INSERT & UPDATE has an impact for strict mode. SELECT fires warning only. dd($records) shows nothing just a blank page.

Comment: dd($records) show 
    "select `a`.*, SUM(a.perday) as revenue, `b`.`name`, `b`.`checkin`, `b`.`checkout`, `b`.`status` from `history` as `a` inner join `reservation2` as `b` on `a`.`id` = `b`.`id` and `a`.`sid` = `b`.`sid` where `a`.`date` between ? and ? group by `a`.`id`, `a`.`sid`" 
if I copy this query to mysql command prompt & replace both ? with '2016-12-01' & '2016-12-05' then many records are displayed.

Comment: Hey it was strict mode true problem. Thanx Mr. Tomas